# combine multiple variables in cell to one variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to change the positions of spellers to a simple format. By changing RW to forward or CM to midfielder. Only there are several values ​​in a cell. How do I combine or drop the other values ​​in the cell?

| player | player_positions |
| --- | --- |
| messi | RW, ST, CF |
| Ronaldo | ST,LW |

how do i change RW, ST, CF just simple to Forward?
Am trying:
`df.replace(to_replace=r'^RW', value='Forward', regex=True)`
but then i get:

| player | player_positions |
| --- | --- |
| messi | Forward, ST, CF |
| Ronaldo | ST,LW |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add everything in the replace statement.

df = df.replace(to_replace=r'^RW, ST, CF', value='Forward', regex=True)

or

df = df.replace(to_replace=r'^RW\D*', value='Forward', regex=True)

Comment: Thanks Felix! The last code did exactly what I wanted. Cheers :)